# IMPORTRANGE and SUM funcions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working with this function =SUM(IMPORTRANGE("Link", "Sheet!A2:A15")) and it works fine, but now I have issue with cases, where the SUM is not a range but seperate cells, for example:
=SUM(IMPORTRANGE("Link", "Sheet!A2,A8,A15"). How can I fix this?

Comment: It would be better to use a different function than SUM(). Why those cells? What is significant about them? what is written next to them that makes you know that they are the cells to SUM? Please provide more and better context.

Answer (score 1):

its either:

```
=SUM(IMPORTRANGE("Link", "Sheet!A2"),
     IMPORTRANGE("Link", "Sheet!A8"), 
     IMPORTRANGE("Link", "Sheet!A15"))
```

or:

```
=SUM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("Link", "Sheet!A1:A15")), 
 "select Col2,Col8,Col15"))
```